# Trying to call function through user input

Tags: python, string, function

```
def monster(name):

    with open('yvd.txt') as fd:
        input=[x.strip('|').split('|') for x in fd.readlines()]
        to_search={x[0]:x for x in input}
        print('\n'.join(to_search[name]))
monster_name=input('Input monster to search: ')
monster(monster_name)
```

Ok so I'm trying to call the function `monster` through user input. The `input` asks the user to enter a name of a monster to search for. The function `monster` then searches for the inputted monster and prints it out. But how do I get it to have the string be callable in the function?

Example of output:

```
Input monster to search: Boogie Man
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Trevor\Desktop\yvd_read.py", line 8, in <module>
    monster(monster_name)
    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get it to have the string be callable in the function"?

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean. Maybe you should describe your question more clearly. It's better if you can give a sample of your input and output.

Comment: monster_name would be a name of a monster so it'd be a string, I want that name to be the argument in for the function monster.  But I'm getting the error "str object is not callable"

Comment: Edit your question and post the error in it please (the whole error: the traceback, etc)

Comment: I tried your code with Python 3.2.3 and I couldn't reproduce the error.  You see the error with exactly the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the method [input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input). You should use [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead. input try to eval the string, but raw_input just put the string writed by the user in the variable.

Comment: I'm using 3.3 so raw_input isn't used anymore

Comment: The error says that you're using python 2.x are you sure that you' re using python 3.x?

Comment: Pretty sure. Says 3.3.0 everywhere.

Comment: The error says that python is trying to eval your string, but that only happens in python 2.x with method input. please add the full traceback.

Comment: That is the all of the traceback.

Comment: How it says @Vaughn Cato, your error isn' t replicable in python 3.x, how did you installed python? did you installed several times?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the python in-built function raw_input to read values instead of input.  Please refer the documentation of [input function here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input). Here is the updated code:

```
def monster(name):

with open('yvd.txt') as fd:
    user_input=[x.strip('|').split('|') for x in fd.readlines()]
    to_search={x[0]:x for x in input}
    print('\n'.join(to_search[name]))

monster_name=raw_input('Input monster to search: ')
monster(monster_name)
```

Comment: I can't. I'm using 3.3 and raw_input isn't used in 3.3 anymore. The other guy thought the same thing.